# Automatically calculate a value in Microsoft Access after user input

Tags: database, ms-access

I made an Acces database where the user can enter the client name, the price he has to pay, etc. (it is a payment management database).

I want to make it so when the user inputs the price, it automatically puts (in another field) the price, but calculates the price + VAT.

How can I do this? Or Is this even possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that there are four different rates of VAT (standard, reduced, zero and exempt), and that the first two may vary over time. You may want to consider a table that has the four VAT titles, and another table that has from/to dates with the actual VAT rates for each of these.

Comment: Thank you, Applecore!

Answer (score 0):

For that other field, use a *ControlSource* like:

```
=[Price]*(1+[VAT])
```

or, to avoid error for empty fields:

```
=Nz([Price])*(1+Nz([VAT]))
```

Comment: Should I put that in a macro, or where so it can run right after the user inputs the price?

Comment: Use it as ControlSource for a textbox on your form.